# How to spin a prerelease Org? (Sign-me-up button doesn't work)

Tags: developer-edition, pre-release

I filled in the form at https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring16-partner.jsp but pressing the Sign-me-up button, nothing happens.

Reloading the page doesn't help. I tried it with firefox and chrome. In the console the is an entry "com.salesforce.www.App: wireModule: Error wiring module: form-builder; undefined" and some SHA-1 issues, but I doubt that it's the reason.

Is there a different way to spin a prerelease Org?

Further I noticed that some DE-orgs on gs0 seem to expire while others does not expire. On org I'm using now for about 2 years and a second I spun 2015 seems to be gone. Will DE-prerelease orgs by default expire or not?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring16.jsp

The one you posted looks like a partners link.

These are trail orgs, and expire 30 days after spin up.

Comment: Thanks, but this link also doesn't work for me - I just checked it. And since we are partners the other link should work, too.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is no longer present. Today I was able to spin a Pre-release Developer Edition for partner with the exact same link shown above.

I have no idea, why it did not worked yesterday. I filled the form exactly the same.

I will not delete but keep this question in case it happens again for someone else. The solution/suggestion/workaround would be: "Wait and try it again tomorrow"